# How bind reactive form to md-select?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have a simple reactive form:

```
this.filterForm = this.fb.group({
      'type': ['', [Validators.required]]
});
```

And Angular Material element:

```
<form [formGroup]="filterForm">
   <md-select formControlName="type"></md-select>
</form>
```

When I subscribed on changes:

```
this.filterForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
        console.log(val);
    });
```

It does not work for material, what do I wrong?

I tried also this:

```
[formControlName]="type"
```

Comment: It's really hard to debug this issue without any replicable sample. Would it be possible for you to create a Sample StackBlitz replicating your issue?

Comment: Where have you initialized your form. Where are you subscribing to changes on it?

Comment: I have initialized in constructor of class(component) and subscribed in `ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.filterForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
        console.log(val);
    });
  }`

Comment: I suspect Reactive Form does not work with Material in Angular 2

Comment: Try moving everything to `ngOnInit`

Comment: Okay, lets check

Comment: Yes, it works in NgOnInit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving everything to the `ngOnInit` instead of `constructor` and `ngOnChanges`.

Reasons: `constructor`s should be as light-weight as possible. And `ngOnChanges` is triggered on an `@Input` property change and not on a change in the `form` value

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'select-value-binding-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-value-binding-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-value-binding-example.css'],
})
export class SelectValueBindingExample {
  filterForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filterForm = this.fb.group({
      'type': ['', [Validators.required]]
    });

    // To change if anything in the form changed.    
    this.filterForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      console.log(val);
    });

    // To change if just type in the form changed.
    this.filterForm.get('type').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      console.log(val);
    });
  }
}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-on-changes?file=app/select-value-binding-example.ts) for your ref.

Although I'm using one of the later versions of Angular Material, this should still work.

Comment: How to check if property `type` was changed?

Comment: Good catch @SiddAjmera